# How to insert record against all rows of one table to another as a foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, loops, database-design

I've Three tables which  are interconnected with each other.

```
Table 1 : Cities
Table 2 : Services
Table 3 : CompanyServices
```

Now Let's Say Cities table have following data

```
CityID   CityName
 1         Mumbai
 2         Delhi
 3         All Cities
```

Services Table have following data

```
ServiceID   ServiceName
 1           Registration
 2           Washing
```

Now let's say user has selected **Registration** service against **All Cities**

So, I'm going to receive `3 as CityID and 1 as ServiceID`

In this case I have to insert the 2 records in CompanyServices table,
Do I need to run loop on city table and insert all the records ? or there is any other solution exists ? because I may have 1000's of cities in future.

**CompanyServices Table Structure**

```
CompanyServiceID      CompanyID       ServiceID     CityID
```

Comment: Just do `INSERT...SELECT...`

Comment: THINK before coding or designing. What happens to all existing registrations when you add a city? Or delete a city? Logically, Option 3 (all cities) is a kludge for your application GUI - it is not a true city. And "1000's of cities in future" is simply wishful thinking and premature optimization. However no one but you knows what entities you are actually modelling so this is all guesswork.